# Как сверстать макет подобным образом?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Список ли это, либо что-то другое. Как подобное делать ума не прилагаю.

Это активити. Архитектура разделений не очевидна. Каким образом сабхидеры(Today, October 15) и `CardView` ниже разделяются?

Очень желательно с примером кода, если вдруг кто подобное реализовывал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну это уж совсем просто, вот линк на секционный адаптер. https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter

Comment: @Chaynik не сталкивался с подобным, теперь хотя бы примерно представляю куда копать. Оформите, пожалуйста - как ответ.

Comment: Как пример посмотрите [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573070/177345). Это основной принцип построения такого адаптера, конкретная логика зависит от организации отображаемых данных - по каким признакам определелять, когда выводить подзаголовок

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот накидал разметку:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorButtonNormal">
    <TextView
        android:text="Date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rel1">
    <TextView
        android:text="term"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Relation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Cartoon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Adventure time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    <TextView
        android:text="idi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/flag30"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
    <Button
        android:text="Edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/button" />
    <Button
        android:text="Delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/someview4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="term"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Synonim"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="118dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="141dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="143dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/flag30"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Скрин.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А остальными данными рулите через адаптер.

Comment: Спасибо за потраченное время