# RecyclerView - добавление header

Tags: android, recyclerview

Здравствуйте. Необходимо сделать заголовки в `RecyclerView` по этой схеме

```
А
Анна
Алексей
...
Б
Борька
...
В
Ваня
```

Список уже в отсортированном виде передаётся в адаптер, но я никак не соображу как прописать эту логику. Примерно понимаю так:

1) Создать две константы для двух типов (`HEADER_ITEM`, `NORMAL_ITEM`).

2) В методе `getItemViewType` по какому-то алгоритму вычислять когда слова на букву заканчиваются и в этом случае возвращать `HEADER_ITEM`.

3) В `onCreateViewHolder` в зависимости от типа айтема создавать разные холдеры.

А дальше не понятно. Выходит, нужно 2 холдера? И как же биндить данные? И ещё такое вопрос - что будет с позицией? Надеюсь, в `RecyclerView` додумали, что хедер не должен содержать в себе позицию. Или для этого и создаются два холдера? Объясните пожалуйста, недавно перешёл на ресайклер с `ListView` и многое кажется сложным

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573070/177345 Логика определения простейшая - берете первую букву и если она не такая же, как у прошлой записи, то выводите заголовок, адаптер такой же, как по ссылке.

Comment: И не надейтесь, додумывать всю логику отображения айтемов и что будет с позицией вам предлагается самостоятельно. В `RecyclerView` нет никаких готовых реализаций хедеров и чего бы то ни было. Вообще, таких адаптеров много на [GitHub уже готовых](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=recyclerview+section&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда нужен хедер его создаю программно.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае проще всего объединить лайауты хедера и айтема в 1 лайаут. Т.е. описанным вами способом определяем тип айтема и исходя из типа создаем ViewHolder с хедером или без хедера. В таком случае можно обойтись одним холдером с разными лайаутами, хотя обычно для каждого типа используется свой холдер и приходится использовать приведение типов. И так вам не придется писать сложную логику про position.

Comment: Как-то костыльно. За такой код меня <line-through>не сожгут на костре</line-through> не уволят?

Comment: @СергейГрушин согласен, костыльно. Но полноценная реализация будет намного сложнее, хоть и универсальнее. В полноценном варианте надо решать вопрос с position или передавать в адаптер список, включающий хедер как элемент. Или использовать библиотеку, вроде StickyListHeaders, но для RecyclerView, а такие библиотеки монструозны.

Comment: Ок, а как насчёт `ListView`?

Comment: @СергейГрушин Для ListView есть отличная [библиотека](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders), она решает все проблемы с хедерами

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал блок с хедером просто невидимым, когда он не нужен. И не нужно лепить несколько layouts, viewholders и т.д.