# Android: Можно-ли что-нибудь вставить перед CardView?

Tags: java, android, xml

Как известно, в работающем приложении `CardView` в подавляющем большинстве генерируются и выводятся программно. Можно ли-чтонибудь вставить перед определённой карточкой?

Пример: добавление TextView в приложении типа галереи перед карточкой с фото и названием фото:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так же смотрите [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573070/177345) с более подробным описанием, как сделать заголовки самому. Возможно вам будет удобнее использовать одну из [готовых библиотек](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=android+section+recyclerview).

Answer (score 1):

Можно. можно у `RecyclerView` переопределить метод `getItemViewType(int position)`. Соответственно при создание `ViewHolder` в методе `onCreateViewHolder` вы будете знать тип, и можете соответственно создавать другой item

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!  К сожалению, не совсем Вас понял: как именно переопределить `getItemViewType(int position)` и как это позволит знать типы?

Comment: У вас по каким то же данным можно определить что в этом item нужно добавить `TextView`. Вы можете эти данные узнавать в  `getItemViewType(int position)` доставая их по позиции. Вот пример http://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/7104538